# Full-text search error during full-text index population : Error Code '0x80092003'

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have problem with Full-Text Search service in production environment.

Each time I rebuild full-text catalog, there is no error in User Interface, but there is no data in Full-Text Catalog

Item Count : 0
Catalog size : 0 MB

OS : Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack2

SQL Server Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (Intel X86)   Oct 14 2005 00:33:37   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

It work on dev server (windows xp professional version 2002 service pack 3) but error on prod server (Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack2)

This is error log.

Scrawl Log:

2010-06-02 03:51:31.06 spid24s     Informational: Full-text Full population initialized for table or indexed view '[test1].[dbo].[test]' (table or indexed view ID '37575172', database ID '9'). Population sub-tasks: 1.

2010-06-02 03:51:31.06 spid24s     Error '0x80092003' occurred during full-text index population for table or indexed view '[test1].[dbo].[test]' (table or indexed view ID '37575172', database ID '9'), full-text key value 0x00000006. Attempt will be made to reindex it.

2010-06-02 03:51:31.06 spid24s     The component 'MSFTE.DLL' reported error while indexing. Component path 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\MSFTE.DLL'.

2010-06-02 03:51:31.06 spid24s     Error '0x80092003' occurred during full-text index population for table or indexed view '[test1].[dbo].[test]' (table or indexed view ID '37575172', database ID '9'), full-text key value 0x00000005. Attempt will be made to reindex it.

Comment: Do you have regular maintenance jobs running? such as Check DB...?

Answer (score 0):

I run maintenance jobs to backup db.
Now it work but i don't know what an error.
I update sql server 2005 to service pack 3.

Sorry for my poor english and thank you for your help.